# django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis vs django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2

Tags: database, django, postgresql, gis, postgis

If a gis application has some tables which don't have gis related columns, does the performance   better when use multiple databases (django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 and django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis) compared using django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis only?

Multiple Databases also introduce some performance overhead and complexity. Could anyone show me the best practice for this scenario?

Comment: Have you figured this out?? I started a gis app today and am wondering the same thing. any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The performance difference will be almost completely invisible.  django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis just extends django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2 to add the PostGiS types.  It is definitely not worth going through the complexity of multiple databases just to use the two different backends.

Comment: Your answer save my day.